# Why won't Poco C++ build on iOS using OpenSSL 1.1.0d?

Tags: c++, ios, openssl, poco, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use OpenSSL 1.1.0d with Poco v1.7.8 and everything seems to be fine on Android & Win32, but there's a compile problem building for iOS.

Specifically, PocoCrypto won't build because X509Certificate.cpp generates "undeclared identifier" errors for these:

```
ASN1_STRING_data
X509_get_notAfter
X509_get_notBefore
```

This appears to be because these identifiers are deprecated in OpenSSL 1.1.0x, but I had no trouble building the same source for Android & Windows. Neither Android nor Windows builds used the "OPENSSL_API_COMPAT" or "OPENSSL_USE_DEPRECATED" macros

I tried using those macros on the iOS version, but got the same errors.

I'm also getting undeclared identifiers in PocoNet/SSL:

```
DH_new
DH_free
BN_bin2bn
DH_set0_pqg
DH_set_length
TLSv1_method
TLSv1_client_method
TLSv1_server_method
```

How do I get Poco to build successfully on iOS in this scenario?

Comment: *" ...I'm also getting undeclared identifiers in PocoNet/SSL.."* - It sounds like your link is failing completely. I'm guessing the issue is with a completely missing OpenSSL library; and not a compatibility issue. Perhaps you should show the full link command.

Comment: It's not a linker problem, it never gets that far.  I thought it was deprecated functions, but turning those on made no difference.

Comment: You should probably show your compile and link command, and the exact error message (or a sampling of them). Otherwise, there's not much we can do other than to say, fix your path problems.

Comment: My paths are fine.  It's not complaining that it couldn't find the openSSL headers, it's saying the specified symbols don't exist in those headers.  The question is, how is that possible?  Looking at the source code, I can see that (for example) the definition of 'ASN1_STRING_data()' is wrapped in a 'DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0' macro.  That macro is in turn wrapped by a '#if OPENSSL_API_COMPAT' block.  And for a value >= '0x10100000L' it stubs a function declaration to nil (i.e. that function does not exist).  Since I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.0d, this seems like a likely culprit. Continued below...

Comment: However, I'm using the same version of OpenSSL on Android, Windows, and iOS -- but only iOS is having this issue.  Perhaps only iOS is built without 'OPENSSL_USE_DEPRECATED'?

Comment: I tried manually modifying opensslconf.h to set 'OPENSSL_MIN_API =0' (which is the default anyway), to set 'OPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x10000000L', and to ensure 'OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED' was not defined.  Still get the same errors.